# Reloading .sql file from java into PostgreSQL - Windows

Tags: postgresql, windows, java, scripting

I am trying to reload a `.sql` script file into PostgreSQL from my sample Java application.

Script is successfully executed from console as well as from pgAdmin tool. But from Java, it hangs...

This is the code I am using:

```
C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql.exe -U postgres -d sampledb -f "H:/Data/samplescript_postgres.sql"
```

Can anyone help me? I am using PostgreSQL 9.2

Java code:

```java
String path = "H:/Data/samplescript_postgres.sql";
final String cmd = "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql.exe -U postgres -d sampledb -f " + "\""+ path + "\" ";

try {
    reloadProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    if(null!=reloadProcess){
        if(reloadProcess.waitFor()==0){
            System.out.println("Reloaded");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My pg_hba.conf file:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER    ADDRESS         METHOD  
# IPv4  local   connections:    
host    all         all     127.0.0.1/32    md5 
# IPv6  local   connections:    
host    all         all     ::1/128         md5
```

Comment: Please show the Java code you are using to invoke the command.

Comment: waits for password?

Comment: When it 'hangs', does it produce any (error) meassages?  Does it start and hang at a later point in execution or looks like doing nothing at all?

Comment: The sql script contains 7 tables, first 2 are only loaded from java.

Comment: How I give password with the above command?

Comment: @Haseena I think you cannot give a password this way.  Are Java and PostgreSQL running on the same machine?

Comment: Yes. I follow the this link http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html

Comment: @Haseena you have to set DB access in pg_hba.conf as well.  Being on the same machine, you can allow `postgres` user to access all local databases without a password by adding a line to pg_hba.conf.  Could you show the relevant rows of this file?  (The rows beginning with 'local' would be enough, I think.)  However, connecting from an application as `postgres` isn't a wise idea generally.

Comment: # TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD 

# IPv4 local connections: 
host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5 
# IPv6 local connections: 
host all all ::1/128 md5

Answer (score 2):

This is probably *not* the best way to do what you want to do.  The "proper" way would probably be to execute the SQL commands in your file via jdbc.

That said, that's a long way from where you are now, and we can probably make what you are trying to do work.

The likely problem is that there is a space in the path to psql.exe.

When you use that particular format of exec, java uses a vanilla string tokenizer to split your string into an array, each entry being separated by a space.  So it's going to be trying to execute a command "`c:/Program`" and pass it parameters, the first of which is "`Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql.exe`" and, um, that isn't going to go so well.

Use `exec (String[])` instead:
[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D%29)

This method doesn't apply the tokenizer, because it's accepting an array, so it doesn't think it needs to.

Try this:

```
String path = "H:/Data/samplescript_postgres.sql";
final String [] cmd = { "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/bin/psql.exe",
       "-U", "postgres",
       "-d", "sampledb",
       "-f", path 
     };

try {
    reloadProcess = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
    if(null!=reloadProcess){
        if(reloadProcess.waitFor()==0){
            System.out.println("Reloaded");
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can see that I've created the array manually.  For readability, I've put the option `"-U"` and the value `"postgres"` on the same line, but they're separated by a comma.

Comment: Do you know any method in Java for running batch SQL against PostgreSQL?

Comment: This looks like a pretty good tutorial: http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Using `psql` this way isn't quite what it was developed for, so you may be surprised when it doesn't behave the same as called from the command line.

As sufleR suggested in a comment, it is possible that `psql` waits for a password.  But you don't have any means to provide one...  So, you have to avoid using a password by adding a row to your pg_hba.conf file:

```
local   sampledb    postgres    trust
```

(Rows starting with `local` generally go before rows starting with `host`.)

If I understand you correctly, this is only a test setup, and then it is OK.  In production applications it is a bad idea to connect to a database with the `postgres` user.  Ideally, every application-database pair should have its own user (or role in database terms).

Comment: From commandline also I cannot give any password. But it works properly

Comment: Is this issue with jdbc?

Comment: @Haseena from command line it looks up the password in the `.pgpass` file.  I don't think that Java can do that.  (And it looks like there is nothing JDBC does in this piece of code.)  Have you tried what I've suggested?

Comment: Tried.... But when I trying to reopen the pgAdmin tool, it shows an error like :   

Error connecting to the server: FATAL:  could not load pg_hba.conf

Comment: Why pgAdmin?  Otherwise, you have to reload PostgreSQL config to get the new pg_hba.conf working.

Comment: From console also it shows the same error

Comment: It means that you have a problem in the file.  How does it look now?

Comment: @Haseena Sorry, my mistake - in Windows the 'local' rows are of no use (and apparently invalid).  It is for Unix and linux machines.

Comment: Then how can I fix it in windows?

Comment: Try to add a line: `host    pathfinder     postgres     127.0.0.1/32   trust`

Comment: # TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD # IPv4 local connections: local sampledb postgres trust host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5 # IPv6 local connections: local sampledb postgres trust host all all ::1/128 md5 # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the # replication privilege. #host replication postgres 127.0.0.1/32 md5 #host replication postgres ::1/128 md5

Comment: But same hang issue still exist...